# How to make sure the UI always shrinks and fit to the window irrespective of the resolution and device via viewport or CSS

Tags: css, html

I want to shrink my UI and make it fit on multiple devices irrespective of the device resolution, so that there wont be any horizontal scroll on the page.

PFB my meta viewport value,

```
<meta content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
```

My website is not a responsive design and i dont want to set the initial-scale and minimum-scale to 1.0 (Although i know like this should be used for most of the websites, For my current site i dont want to use it.)

On most of the devices, my website container width is 1200px, since i have not set the initial-scale and minimum-scale, even if i view my website on any device even with resolution is less than 1200px (w.r.t) width, The UI shrinks and fits the screen on the device with full width without a horizontal scroll.

I'm facing the issue on old iPad devices, where the UI is not fitting the exactly to the width of the screen, but overflowing horizontally by introducing a horizontal scroll bar in the page. Is there a way i can fix this issue, so that irrespective of screen resolution the UI always shrinks and fits to the device screen.

I'm not seeing this issue on Android device, but the issue is coming up on old iPad device.

Please let me know if there is any solution to fix this issue on iPad.

Comment: Add your html / css

Comment: @ILoveCSS Have updated the question with the URL of the site, I'm not seeing this issue in the landing page, but when navigated to the Store-Finder page using the link in the left top corner, that page and few other is the site is getting rendered with a horizontal scroll

Comment: try this `<meta content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">`

Comment: @AnujaAgarwal Thanks mate. It worked perfect.

Comment: can I write that as a proper answer so you can accept it, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `meta` tag to inside your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```